# Why is the compileall module not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm testing compiling Python code, but when I run the `compileall` module on a directory with a test file in it, it skips the directory and goes and compiles the Standard Library for some reason. Why is it doing this?

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the full path.

Comment: More details needed. Are you running it from the command line with `-m` or as part of a script you wrote? Are you calling `compile_path` instead of `compile_dir`?

Comment: @Cairnarvon - I'm doing `python -m compileall` in the directory that the test file is in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're running `python -m compileall` without specifying a directory, and the module is doing [exactly what the documentation says it should](http://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html#command-line-use): compiling every directory in `sys.path`.

To compile only the directory you're currently in, pass it on the command line:

```
$ python -m compileall .
```